# ScrollView cause CPU Usage to 100% in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, xcode11

I am trying to create a Horizontal list of Images and I wrote below code in SwiftUI but I am not sure what is wrong here but CPU Usage and Ram reached to the maximum level.

I thought it is because of WebImage but it's not working for Rectangle either so there must be something related to the code I wrote.

```
private let reader = UIScreen.main.bounds

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 0 ) {
                ForEach(self.images, id: \.self){ imageURL in
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width:self.reader.size.width, height: self.reader.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .border(Color.black,width: 10.0)
//                            WebImage(url: URL.init(string: imageURL))
//                                .resizable()
//                                .indicator(.activity) // Activity Indicator
//                                .scaledToFill()
//                                .frame(width:self.reader.size.width, height: self.reader.size.height, alignment: .center)
//                                .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
    }.onAppear {
        UIScrollView.appearance().isPagingEnabled = true
    } 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to get each rectangle/image to fill the screen and scroll horizontally then this should do the job:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 0 ) {
                ForEach(self.images, id: \.self){ imageURL in
                    Color.green
                        .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .border(Color.black,width: 10.0)
//                              WebImage(url: URL.init(string: imageURL))
//                                  .resizable()
//                                  .indicator(.activity) // Activity Indicator
//                                  .scaledToFill()
//                                  .frame(width:self.reader.size.width, height: self.reader.size.height, alignment: .center)
//                                  .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            UIScrollView.appearance().isPagingEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

That doesn't rely on the screen bounds but uses a GeometryReader to get the size of the contain the scroll view is inside.

Also a point to remember is that all the rectangles/images will get created at once there is no caching of a scroll view so if you have a lot there could be a performance hit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have to show images instead of static colors so this will not work.
There are maximum of 4 images so I believe it should create a performance issue.

Comment: There is nothin there stopping you from using images I just used the static colour as an example in the same way as you were using `Rectangle()` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the issue in Xcode 11.5 itself as this code works fine now.

```
ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 0 ) {
                    ForEach(self.images, id: \.self){ imageURL in
                        WebImage(url: URL.init(string: imageURL))
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .center)
                            .clipped()
                            .background(Color.white)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You will still have the possibility of the same issue as your proxy is based on the `UIScreen.main.bounds` and the view will probably be that size because of things such as the status bar, navigation bar (if you use one), etc.  It's not really a good idea to base anything inside a SwiftUI view directly on `UIScreen.main.bounds`